# How work DataSet TableAdapter Properties Connection - "ConnectionString(Settings)". It's temporary?

Tags: c#, dataset, dataset-designer

In small company I have a big problem with make changes in bigand old counting program(GS).

When we have old empty connection string in TableAdapter in DataSet all work fine. When i update view in DB, make new string to DB in TableAdapter.

All works fine. I add new column and make all next ToDo things.

But when i COMMIT solution on SVN and my boss run it. He can't connect to his local DB. When after all my ToDo with DataSet i back to old string, I can't build project.

I try make changes in properties/app.config/DataSet XML but...

I don't know how to resolve. Nobody knows.

Hence my question.

1. How work DataSet TableAdapter ConnectionString? 
   1.1 Until now we tought its only for work in Designer and when we run program(GS) the TableAdapter take connection string from GS settings(imported to own class settings from XML file).
2. When we have old empty string all work fine. But we cant change query. Maybe make and sign to TableAdapter new string make changes in deep code(where...) and crush our solution.

Please help me I spent many days on this problem. This is second approach to the problem of a few week. I can't ask anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Resolve problem is simply. In SolutionExplorer > Project > Properties > F7 i have override propertis.  And i extend funded method of "|| propertyName == "ConnectionString3". 
Method:

```
public override object this[string propertyName]
{
get
{
if (propertyName == "XXXXConnectionString" || propertyName == "XXXXConnectionString3")
{
return Databases.SkarbDB.ConnectionString;
}
else
{
return base[propertyName];
}
}
}
```